# Are simpleflake ids generarated in different languages consistent?

Tags: javascript, python, uniqueidentifier, distributed-system

I need to generated unique Ids in distributed manner. Some at server side and another at client side. Server side programming language can be ruby and python while client side is javascript.
I am plannning to use simpleflake libraries for respective languages.

Can I assume that the ids will never collide?

OR they can collide often, due to the implementation details in different packages?

Thanks in advance.

-Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's [Simpleflake](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simpleflake) and Node.js's [simpleflakes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simpleflakes) are actually derived from same origin (python's implementation). Both generate 64bit IDs And IDs generated by both are compatible with each other.

The simple flake generates id with the [formula](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1k7du3/simpleflake_distributed_id_generation_for_the/)

```
flake = (int((time.time() - 946702800) * 1000) << 23) + random.SystemRandom().getrandbits(23)
```

As pointed out in earlier answer, the **probability of collision is really low** (It is the probability of clashing **41 bit timestamp** in *milliseconds* and the probability of ***randomly generated 23 bit integer***).

However, it'd be important to know the difference between two implementations mentioned above. The simpleflakes node.js library fixes its epoch at 2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z whereas python implementation assumes the epoch at 2000-01-01T05:00:00.000Z.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Simpleflake itself, but have been using a similar scheme for years, though I use 128 bits instead of 64.

The key ingredient is that most of the bits are random. So even if your libraries choose a slightly different number of bits for the timestamp portion, or a different granularity then the likelihood of collisions is low. Of course, in such cases it lessens the speed improvements in the database.

I imagine that some Simpleflake implementation is "standard" and the other implementations are straight ports---keeping compatibility and characteristics. If not, shame on them for using *Simpleflake* in their name.

Comment: Thanks. I will also assume for now that it is safe to use those libraries across languages. If I find some more info, I will post it here too.